# MySQL - Join two tables, different columns in table 1 on the same column in table 2

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to join a different column (`part_type_n` (where n ranges from 1 to 54)) on `Table1` with the same column (`id`, primary, autoinc) on `Table2`.

Schema:

```
Table1
==============
part_type_1
.
.
.
part_type_54



Table2
=============
id
```

I tried the obvious query (php generated, looping through n from 1 to 54), omitted repetitive stuff in ...:

`SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 on (Table1.part_type_1=Table2.id), ..., (Table1.part_type_54=Table2.id)`

I receive this error:

## 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'Table2'

How do I join these two tables?

Comment: In this case, would it be better to just use 54 separate calls instead of a single call?

Comment: Do you really want to select only those records from table1 which have table2 records matching all 54 part_type values?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to join the table on it self again multiple times.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t2.Id=t1.part_type_1 
INNER JOIN table2 t3 on t3.id = t1.part_type_54;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: why inner join and not join

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins?sort=newest%3E

Comment: JOIN is shorthand for INNER JOIN - is there a reason to not use shorthand

Comment: There is absolutely no difference in performance as well as implementation. I just personally prefer to write Inner Join as its much cleaner to read.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to writing a query with 54 table aliases, you could consider joining to the table once - like so:

```
select ...
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2
  on t2.id in (t1.part_type_1, t1.part_type_2, ... t1.part_type_54)
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to get my required result as one row of which matches various categories all stored in one table column.

**Query**

```
       SELECT cm3.*, xp.post_title,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sc.name) AS cate_list
       FROM `xld_posts` xp 
       JOIN course_map cm0 ON cm0.course_id = xp.ID
       JOIN course_map cm1 ON cm1.course_id = cm0.course_id  AND cm0.id = 3
       JOIN course_map cm2 ON cm2.course_id = cm1.course_id  AND cm1.id = 6
       JOIN course_map cm3 ON cm3.course_id = cm2.course_id  AND cm2.id = 11
       JOIN subject_category sc ON cm3.id = sc.id
       GROUP by post_title ORDER BY post_title
```

Note: the categories values 3, 6, and 7 are got from form sumbit. Thus if your form has more than three or less your query should dynamically created and join each table with previous table.

:) Happy if any one felt useful.